# Where can I find the Google Maps API Premium account client and signature?

Tags: matrix, maps, distance, credentials

I recently upgrade my Google Maps API to a premium one and need to provide client and signature on calls to distance matrix, but can't find those information on the Google Cloud Console.

Comment: [Google API key and digital signature documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/get-api-key)